# Error Consulta dbf (Fox Pro) con c# (c sharp)

Tags: c#, odbc, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Estoy abriendo una tabla dbf (fox pro) con una aplicación de consola de C# la cuestión es que cuando realizo la consulta en la tabla dbf me da un error en la aplicación de c#:

> (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Se utilizó un numero incorrecto de
>   argumentos con la función en la expresión de consulta 'FECHA >=
>   date(2017,06,01)')

la consulta completa es `"SELECT * FROM VENTA WHERE FECHA >= date(2017,06,01)"` utilizo `between`, le quito el "date" pero la consulta sigue sin funcionar.

Ejecuto la consulta sin el `where` y la aplicación funciona perfectamente, el problema es que yo necesito hacer ese filtrado por fecha ya que solo necesito del primero de mes a la fecha

Comment: Intenta usando este formato:  {^yyyy/MM/dd}

Comment: me funciono gracias, como seria con fecha y hora DATETIME(yyyy,mm,dd hh:mm:ss) como se podria agragar por favor

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

> =DATETIME(2016,02,15)

Comment: Esto provocaría un error, trata de obtener reputación para comentar, revisar [answer].